# Please help stock literally screw stuck in wall

Tags: walls

Hello I purchased the wall unit and it was free-floating I had to mounted on the wall I don't like the unit so I took it down there was seven screws that went very deep into the wall I took out six of them one is stuck in there I cannot get it out I've used electric drill I've used hammer and pliers I do use needle nose pliers and twist I have been the bar up and back to try to loosen the screw I believe I've done maybe 2 1/2 rotations to the left for it to come off the wall I have to get this screw out of the wall so I could take care of the damage that he already has made I have been the bar which I don't want to do because I'm trying to resell this piece can someone please help me tell me what I should do nothings working. Desperate on the lake DVA

Comment: Punctuation would help if you actually want answers

Comment: How about a picture? Put a link in your question and we can add the pic.

Answer (score 1):

Get a pair of ViceGrips. Fasten very tightly on the head of the screw and use them to turn the screw out.

Answer (score 0):

Are you saying you have tried to turn it in and then back out this is what I usually try with tough screws. If going through metal many screws strip out the last thread or 2. If the threads on the screw are stripped I pry up on the screw while trying to back it out. This can be tough but ether the screw will back out or the screw breaks off. Can be frustrating. If all else fails you may be able to rock the screw head back and forth and break it off then shove it in. Option 2 would be to cut the head off and push it in. I have had to do both in the past.then patch the area around the screw.